# Elastic Search Rollup Jobs

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

> Can I filter the documents in elastic search before rolling them up, or can I define filter query in Roll up job, If yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to filter data before rolling it up into a new rolled up index. However, you can achieve what you want by first defining a [filtered alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered) and then rolling up on that alias.

Say, you want to roll up index `test` but only for customers 1, 2 and 3. You can create the following filtered alias:

```
POST /_aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "test",
        "alias": "filtered-test",
        "filter": { "terms": { "customer.id": [1, 2, 3] } }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And then you can roll up on the `filtered-test` alias instead of the `test` index and that will only roll up data from customers 1, 2 and 3:

```
PUT _rollup/job/sensor
{
  "index_pattern": "filtered-test",
  "rollup_index": "customer_rollup",
  ...
}
```

PS: It is worth noting that [you're not alone](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/38837) but Elastic folks specifically decided not to allow filtering in roll-ups for various reasons (you can read more in the issue I linked to). The issue has been reopened because there's a [big refactor of the roll up feature](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/42720) going on. Stay tuned...